# Static linking boost libraries to each other through Jamfile

Tags: c++, boost

We have a simple project containing a jamfile that links to libraries in another project.
The problem is, boost doesn't detect any changes made to these libraries at all.

For eg. We have Projects A and B

A links to B/libb1 and B/libb2

But when changes to B are made and libb1 and libb2 are updates and installed in the environment, on building A, it doesn't detect any changes  at all.

What could be the possible solutions for this?